# show my blog content in google search

Tags: google, blogger, blog, blogspot

Recently, I created a blog in Blogger.com(or blogspot.com). My problem is that I can't see my content when I search on google for it. Similarly, I created the same page using Wordpress.com which shows the content on search on google.

What should I do to show my content on google search using blogger?

**EDIT**: (*Edited after this [**post**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/48313/26760)*)

More specific question - what part of a blogger blog does google search. I get the impression that it searches the header and the posts, but not the widgets, so if you are using the blog more as a website, your widget content won't get searched. I may be wrong though. Does anyone know exactly what is searched, heading, subheading, widgets and posts?

Please help I am new to blogspot.com or blogger.com

Comment: Google doesn't spider everything instantly, especially new blogs, even on their own property.

Comment: So, it will take time? just now I added google analytics (I don't know much about it).

Comment: I still can't see my content in google search

Comment: Since your question seems to be more about what the Googlebot picks up to add to the index, this question might be better off at [webmasters.se].

Comment: @AlEverett Can you please migrate it there? I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but I can vote for it to be migrated. (As can you.)

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes takes 4-6 weeks for Google to crawl blogspot sites  (though more recently I had a new site that was done in about 5 days).   You cannot directly control it - although a link to your site from a popular forum site in your topic area sometimes speeds things up.

However having the same content in a Wordpress blog is not a good idea.  That is duplicate content, which Google may penalize you for.   So - choose one platform and stick to it for each blog.